# SQL date functions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, sql-date-functions

```
create table sales
(
     sdate DATE,
     samount varchar2(10)
);

insert into sales values('1-FEB-2016',25000);
insert into sales values('2-FEB-2016',45000);
insert into sales values('3-FEB-2016',25000);
insert into sales values('4-FEB-2016',29000);
insert into sales values('5-FEB-2016',75000);
insert into sales values('6-FEB-2016',90000); 
insert into sales values('7-FEB-2016',38000); 

select 
    to_char(sdate, 'day') 
from sales;

select *
from sales 
where to_char(sdate, 'day') = 'monday';
```

Anything wrong with the last line?

The output shown is no data found instead of 1-FEB-2016 25000

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is that when using the `'day'` format option, Oracle puts spaces to pad the length out to `'wednesday'` (the longest date name).  You can check this by seeing if this works:

```
where to_char(sdate, 'day') = 'wednesday'
```

I use the abbreviated forms, anyway, because it is easier to type:

```
where to_char(sdate, 'dy') = 'mon';
```

This behavior is even explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i170559):

> The character elements MONTH, MON, DAY, and DY are padded with
>   trailing blanks to the width of the longest full month name, the
>   longest abbreviated month name, the longest full date name, or the
>   longest abbreviated day name, respectively, among valid names
>   determined by the values of NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE and NLS_CALENDAR
>   parameters.

Comment: where to_char(sdate,'dy')  =  'mon'  is working well for all days but 
where to_char(sdate,'day')  =  'monday' is not working

Comment: @aneela . . . I don't understand your comment.  You specify that in the question and I think my answer explains what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UPPER(to_char(sdate,'fmday'))= 'MONDAY'. Generally there is a space padding for which its showing NO_DATA found error.

Answer (score 0):

You should put qoutes around your second value parameters because they are of varchar type or change the type to integer

Answer (score 0):

```
   select * from sales where to_char(sdate, 'fmday') = 'monday';
```

Oracle database is designed in such a way that all spellings of day require same amount of space. So since the length wednesday is 9 which is the max length among all days, other days are padded with a blank () if their length is less than 9. So `to_char(sdate, 'fmday')` does not return  `monday` (6 letters) but instead it is returns `monday'   '` (9 letters i.e 6 letters plus 3 additional spaces). To remove those additional blanks you need to use `fm` (the date type format model used to remove additional blanks in date)

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Answer (score -2):

Gap between "*" and "from"...

Thanks.

Comment: Would generate an error if that was the cause, not an empty result set.